# Opentok : Can I check if other client is connected to the session?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, video-streaming, webrtc, opentok

I am using the Opentok library for the video chat.
There will be 2 clients: one is a servant and another one is a lender.
I want to disable the lender to access chatting room if the servant is not connected.

```
startSession(apiKey, sessionId, token) {
    // connect to session
    var self = this;
    self.session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);

    // Subscribe to a newly created stream
    self.session.on("streamCreated", function(event) {
       self.interval = setInterval(self.countTime, 1000);
        self.session.subscribe(
            event.stream,
            "notary-camera",
            {
                insertMode: "append",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                showControls: false
            },
            function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log("Subscriber initialized.");
                }
            }
        );
    });

    // Create a publisher
    self.publisher = OT.initPublisher(
        "client-camera",
        {
            insertMode: "append",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            showControls: false
        },
        function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log("Publisher initialized.");
            }
        }
    );

    // Connect to the session
    self.session.connect(token, function(error) {

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

It's not possible for someone to know if another participant is in the session without being connected to the [Session](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Session.html). They must be connect to the Session so they can listen to the `connectionCreated` event.

However, you can sign up for [Session Monitoring](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/session-monitoring/) which will allow you to get the following events on the server side via a webhook:

- `connectionCreated`
- `connectionDestroyed`
- `streamCreated`
- `streamDestroyed`

You can use these events to store the number of participants and publishers in a session. This will allow participants to poll your servers to see if there is someone already in the session.